# How to point out a place in iframe using latitude and longitude

Tags: openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

I want point out a place using latitude and longitude in following frame,

```
<iframe width="75%" 
        height="550" 
        frameborder="0" 
        scrolling="no" 
        marginheight="0" 
        marginwidth="0" 
        src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=79.84942674636841%2C6.899900944350287%2C79.85650777816772%2C6.90436374803887&amp;layers=ND" 
        style="border: 1px solid black">
</iframe>
```

How should I point out?

Comment: You're saying you want to add a marker to the openstreetmap.org map?

Comment: yes.. i want to add a marker with custom a custom icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=79.84933018684386%2C6.90329331805479%2C79.85746264457703%2C6.908917042549519&marker=6.906105188659279%2C79.85339641571045&layers=ND

Using the 'marker' parameter (as above) is the answer you're looking for.

This can be a little confusing because OSM also uses 'mlat' and 'mlon'
for marker latitude and longitude in other places.

To do this directly from the site, visit:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/6.90611/79.85340&layers=ND

(or however you would normally get to a map)

click the "share" icon, and then check "Include marker".

This will give you a blue marker you can place anywhere on the map.

After doing that, click the HTML button and cut/paste to export the map:

[image]

In the HTML, note that the iframe for the map uses "marker", but the
"View Larger Map" link uses "mlat" and "mlon".

Comment: Is it possible to mark more than 1 places in the same way?